# Using angle chasing to find $\angle{DBF}$

Tags: geometry

The question and partial solution are below.

[image]

I am confused how to angle chase to get $\angle{DBF} = \angle{DFB} = 75^{\circ}$. I drew the diagram below in order to try to figure it out although I couldn't get anywhere without assuming $BD = NE$. Is there a way to prove that or is there a different way to angle chase here to get $\angle{DBF}$ and  $\angle{DFB}$?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

$|FA|=10=|AE|$, then $FAE$ is an isosceles triangle with $\measuredangle AEF=\measuredangle EFA=75^{\circ}$, now, $\triangle FAE$ and $\triangle BDF$ are similar.

Answer (score 0):

From your figure:

$\angle AFE =\angle FEA=75°$ since $AFE$ is isosceles.

and, since $\angle ADE=90°$ we have:

$\angle FAD =\angle EAD=15° \Rightarrow FD=DE$ and $BD=DE$

so: $FD=BD$.